# FirebaseAuth - how can I wait for value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication, kotlin-coroutines

I use FirebaseAuth for registration new user

```
class FirebaseAuthenticationServiceImpl(): FirebaseAuthenticationService {
        
            override fun registerWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String): Boolean {

                val registration = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnSuccessListener {
                        println(it.additionalUserInfo?.providerId.toString())
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        println(it.message.toString())
                    }
                return registration.isSuccessful
            }
}
```

I call function above and every time I get `false`. After some time I get `true`

```
    coroutineScope {
                try {
                    if (firebaseService.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)) {
                        openHomeActivity.offer(Unit)
                    } else {}
                } catch (e: Exception) {}
   }
```

How can I wait for uth result (success/failure) and afer that get that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is FirebaseAuthenticationService from? Do you need it? The official getting started guide just uses `Firebase.auth`. With this, you can authenticate using the `await()` suspend function instead of using the callback approach.

```
// In a coroutine:
val authResult = Firebase.auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()
val user: FirebaseUser = authResult.user
if (user != null) {
    openHomeActivity.offer(Unit)
} else {
    // authentication failed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using coroutines you can use `suspendCoroutine` which is perfect bridge between traditional callbacks and coroutines as it gives you access to the `Continuation<T>` object, example with a convenience extension function for `Task<R>` objects :

```
    scope.launch {
    
       val registrationResult = suspendCoroutine { cont -> cont.suspendTask(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password) }
    
    }
    
    private fun <R> Continuation<R>.suspendTask(task: Task<R>) {
            task.addOnSuccessListener { this.success(it) }
                .addOnFailureListener { this.failure(it) }
        }

    private fun <R> Continuation<R>.success(r : R) = resume(r)
    private fun <R> Continuation<R>.failure(t : Exception) = resumeWithException(t)
```