# Firebase Auth not working in an outside class from the activity

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am making an app with login, signup and so on. For each operation I have a different activity and, to clean up my code, I created a Kotlin class just for the server communication with methods for every server operation. Here it is:

```
package com.mainpackage.provachat

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth

class ServerCommunication {

    private var auth  = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    fun login(activity: android.app.Activity, email: String, psswd: String): Boolean{

        var isLogInSucceeded = false

        auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, psswd)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity) { task ->
                isLogInSucceeded = task.isSuccessful
            }

        return isLogInSucceeded
    }

    fun register(activity: android.app.Activity,  email: String, psswd: String): Boolean{

        var isSignUpSucceeded = false

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, psswd)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity) { task ->
                isSignUpSucceeded = task.isSuccessful
            }

        return isSignUpSucceeded
    }

    //----THE METHODS BELOW WORK PERFECTLY------

    fun disconnectUser(){

        auth.signOut()
    }

    fun isCurrentUserLogged(): Boolean{

        if(auth.currentUser == null){
            return false
        }

        return true
    }
}
```

The problem comes when I try to use the method `login()` or `register()` infact they never succeed. I can tell it because I use a bool to verify if the task in `addOnCompleteListener(activity)` is completed correctly.

Here you are my call of the method login in an activity:

```
var isLoginSucceeded = sc.login(this, email, psswd)
```

I think that the problem is due to the activity object that I pass at `register()` or `login()` with `this`.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Have you tried to check what happens if the Task is not successful?

Comment: I found more in detail what is the problem: the lambda expression. The variable "isLogInSucceeded" is true while it is in the lambda but outside it's false. I found out it doing a print inside (true) and outside (false). So the firebase auth goes well the problem is the bool flag variable which has always false value when I return it. Why is that? Infact if I do not inizialize the variable, android studio says that I must inizialize it. Thanks.

Comment: It's because Firebase API is asynchronous. You cannot simply use that value outside that method, as it takes some time to get the callback.

Comment: Ahh, got it. So what can I do to work around this problem?

Comment: If you are interested in a Firebase Authentication with Google using Kotlin, you can check this [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FireApp/tree/master/app/src/main/java/ro/alexmamo/firebase/auth) out.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work the way you expect it to:

```
fun register(activity: android.app.Activity,  email: String, psswd: String): Boolean{

    var isSignUpSucceeded = false

    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, psswd)
        .addOnCompleteListener(activity) { task ->
            isSignUpSucceeded = task.isSuccessful
        }

    return isSignUpSucceeded
}
```

If you run this code in a debugger (setting breakpoints on every line), or if you add logging you will see that `return isSignUpSucceeded` runs before `isSignUpSucceeded = task.isSuccessful` is ever executed. That is because the call to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` is asynchronous, as it needs to communicate with the servers, and the main code (such as your `return isSignUpSucceeded`) continues to run, so that the user can continue to use you app.

In Java, the solution is to put any code that needs the result of the asynchronous call *inside* the completion listener, or to call it from there. That's pretty much what the task does in the code you already have, and also what is shown in this answer: [Firebase - Android - fetchProvidersForEmail - Why are all the calls asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918459/firebase-android-fetchprovidersforemail-why-are-all-the-calls-asynchronous/41918701#41918701)

With Kotlin, there are some other synchronization primitives though. I recommend you read more about them here: https://www.google.com/search?q=kotlin+wait+for+task+to+finish My best guess from reading some of those is that you can call `await` on the task, as shown here: [FirebaseAuth - how can I wait for value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67626005/firebaseauth-how-can-i-wait-for-value)

Answer (score 0):

You can use callbacks, which you pass to the login function and it gets called on successful login when the task is completed.

```
fun login(activity: android.app.Activity, email: String, psswd: String, callback: (status: Boolean)->Unit){
    

    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, psswd)
            .addOnCompleteListener(activity) { task ->
                 if(task.isSuccessful){
                     callback.invoke(true)
                 }else{
                     callback.invoke(false)
                 }
            }.addOnFailureListener(activity) {
                callback.invoke(false)
            }
    
}
```

then use like this

```
 login(this,"hello","password"){ status ->
        //status is return here as a bool
    }
```